# Java servlet scope

Tags: java, servlets

I have a web application, which has Servlet and a static Class accessed through getInstance:

```
MyServlet extends HttpServet {
 protected void doGet(...) {
  MyClass.getInstance().doStuff();
 }
}
```

When clients connect to the servlet do they get their own intance of MyClass or the instance of this class is global to all servlets? I mean let say it have a static variable that is set during the doGet method, when other clietns access the the web app, will they get the value of the variable set by other client in this static Class?

EDIT:

Specifically, `MyClass` represents a class which access web services, something that is authenticated.

Comment: It entirely depends on what `MyClass.getInstance()` and `doStuff()` do.

Comment: MyClass will represent a class to access external or other web service, so I am concerned with the scope of the class, I mean I dont want other web clients to access the same data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All code in your web application will have access to the same static variable of `MyClass`.

However, it is still bound to play by Java thread model rules.

So, in the absence of synchronization, changing it in `doGet` does not mean that other threads will see the new value automatically.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, a `static` field value is shared within the classloader. So, if `MyClass.getInstance()` returns a `static` field of `MyClass`, it will be shared by all invocations.

Note that there is only one servlet instance, and multiple threads pass through its `doGet(..)` method.

If you need to carry some initialization, you have two options: in `.getInstance()` or in the servlet's `init()` method.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the implementation of MyClass. If it is a singleton, then it is only one instance for all the "instantiations" required to doStuff.

Share its code and people will help you.